# TYPO3: Dynamically redirect to parent page with typoscript

Tags: redirect, typo3, typoscript, http-redirect, typo3-6.2.x

I'm in the process of building a website using TYPO3 6.2.

I have the following page structure:

```
- Page Root (id=0)
   - Page A (id=1, alias=pagea)
      - Content 1 (id=3, alias=content1)
         - Detail 1 (id=5, alias=detail1)
         - Detail 2 (id=6, alias=detail2)
      - Content 2 (id=4, alias=content2)
         - Detail 3 (id=7, alias=detail3)
    - Page B (id=2, alias=pageb)
      - Content 3 (id=4, alias=content3)
```

I am using realURL, so in order to access page with id = 5, the following URL would be valid: `web.site/pagea/content1/detail1`

Pages in the second level (eg Page A) inherit the content of its children (eg Content 1, Content 2). So the "Content X" pages should not be individually browseable and instead redirect to their parent (Page X), with the alias as a hashtag. So if one were to open `web.site/pagea/content1/`, it should redirect to `web.site/pagea/#content1`

I tried accessing the DB and build my individual redirect URL in the redirect-header, but it doesnt replace the {} queries

```
[treeLevel = 2]
  config >
  config.additionalHeaders = HTTP/1.0 301 Permanent Redirect | Location: https://web.site/{levelfield:-2, alias}#{page:alias}
[end]
```

Anyone got a solution to this?

P.S. Setting the Contnet-pages as a shortcut does not work for me, as it looses the hashtag and requires it to be set for each "Content #"-Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type of `config.additionalHeaders` is `string` so trying to access the DB or working with constants inside `config.additionalHeaders` can't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You might find a solution on another layer:
Try to build a regexp in your .htaccess which identifies urls with more than two path segments and rewrite/redirect it to the top-level with an anchor.

As you want to have the same links in your website you might need to use the same replacement as last stdWrap on page generation so every 'normal' deep link is replaced first hand and urls with multiple path segemnts are not known to the world (google) at all.